# Side bar navigation that shows in desktop and pushes on mobile

Tags: mobile, navigation, sidebar

I have been trying to create a vertical left sidebar navigation that shows when the window size is desktop size and collapses when the users resizes the window, shows the hamburger icon, and when the user clicks the icon it pushes the navigation out.

Trying to find a solution everywhere. It is for a admin dashboard I am building. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into using a framework like Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com) or Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Comment: actually just trying to build this from scratch using jquery and css... is this possible?

Comment: @Skram ok, I downloade bootstrap... how would I go about achieving this with bootstrap?